# Py3 Pandas read_csv Insert Items into Dict

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do something simple, but don't know how to read the actual rows from the dataframe. I want to run some regex on each string.

The .csv file has no header, it's just one column full of a bunch of strings.

```
csv_data = pd.read_csv('list.csv', sep=',', header=None)

pattern = re.compile(r'(.*\/)(?!\/)(.*)', flags=re.DOTALL)

url_file = {
        pattern.findall(row)[0]:
        pattern.findall(row)[1]
        for index, row in csv_data.iterrows()
    }
```

But I just get

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

---

**Edit 1**

I do not believe this to be a duplicate, the other suggested SO question/solution is different context and has headers and multiple columns.

---

**Edit 2**

print(csv_data.dtypes)

```
0    object
dtype: object
```

print( csv_data.head())

```
0  https://...
1  https://...
2  https://...
3  https://...
4  https://...
```

---

**Edit 3**

Doing this:

```
for row in csv_data.iterrows():
    print(row.dtypes)
```

gave the error `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dtypes'`

So, it seems the contents are tuples, therefore just need to figure out how to get the string out of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas.read\_csv from string or package data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696479/pandas-read-csv-from-string-or-package-data)

Comment: Can you `print(csv_data.dtypes)` for us? `csv_data.head()` migh help as well.

Comment: @nick I added to the original question those prints, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Major edit. You were right: Yoshitha's solution is not ideal as you specifically want the two elements from that regex match.

However, Pandas does have a nice regex handling solution to help you. Something like this is a lot neater:

`matches = csv_data.iloc[:,0].str.extract(r'(.*\/)(?!\/)(.*)', expand=True)`

And then to get your dictionary representation, we can run:
`matches.set_index(0, drop=True).to_dict()[1]`

This might still have issues if there is a url string in the input that does fully match this regex though.

Simple example:

```
l = ['https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/full/68518-5df5b5e5t5b.jpg', 'test_with_bad_url']
matches = pd.DataFrame(l).iloc[:,0].str.extract(r'(.*\/)(?!\/)(.*)', expand=True)
your_dict = matches.set_index(0, drop=True).to_dict()[1]
print(your_dict)
{'https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/full/': '68518-5df5b5e5t5b.jpg',
 nan: nan}
```

Comment: Hi @nick, thanks for the response! I did get `for index, row in csv_data[0].iteritems()
IndexError: list index out of range` . In regards to Yoshitha, I would like to implement that, but I don't know how: `x:regex_function(x)`

Comment: So it seems then that the regex is not matching on one row in the file. I’ll reply fully shortly.

Comment: Hi @Kenny. `.apply(lambda x: regex_function(x))` is just short hand for saying for each element `x` in the dataframe call `regex_function` with `x` as the input.

Comment: and I make that `regex_function` and just return the output? It's tough to visualize because I'm getting two pieces of data from the regex

Comment: Can you just post an example of what a matched regex should look like?

Comment: Yes: `https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/full/68518-5df5b5e5t5b.jpg`

Comment: Also, I did get this just now: `TypeError: tuple expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`

Comment: @Kenny, you were right. Sorry, I was overlooking the need for returning that tuple from that function. I have changed the way I suggest you tackle this problem. Pandas has a neat way of dealing with regex matches on the columns. See if the above solution works for you.

Comment: This is great, thank you very much for taking the time to help me with this! It seems to be working, I just need to now figure out how to go through my entire .csv file and add it to the dictionary.

Comment: Something weird I'm experiencing, just to add, is that I have 200 lines in my .csv, but only line 177 and 200 are being added to the dictionary. It's skipping the rest. If anything comes to mind, that would be great. Otherwise, thanks again.

Comment: The dictionary has a unique key constraint. This means one of two things. If the regex does not match the string input (i.e., you have some input that does not have the required '/' characters that it is searching for) then the tuple (nan,nan) is added to the dictionary. If there is more than one example then this just overwrites the previous entries. The other reason is you have duplicate entries for the path in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can better use lambda function on this single column and Keep the regex operations in a function and call like this:
Suppose data is the data frame and string is the column name:

```
data = pd.read_csv('list.csv', sep=',', header=None)
data.columns = ['string']
data['string']  = data['string'].apply(lambda x:regex_function(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Yoshitha! Sadly, I don't understand lambda functions very will. I was hoping to get a dictionary of data back from the original .csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this code:

```
csv_data = pd.read_csv('list.csv', sep=',', header=None, dtype=str)
csv_data = csv_data.fillna("")

pattern = re.compile(r'(.*\/)(?!\/)(.*)', flags=re.DOTALL)

url_file = {
        pattern.findall(str(row))[0]:
        pattern.findall(str(row))[1]
        for index, row in csv_data.iterrows()
    }
```

Comment: I tried, I do still have the same error: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`, thanks for your answer though!