# using pandas read_excel to read from stdin

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, stdin

Note: I have solve this problem as per below:

I can use to_csv to write to stdout in python / pandas.  Something like this works fine:

```
final_df.to_csv(sys.stdout, index=False)
```

I would like to read in an actual excel file (not a csv).  I want to output CSV, but input xlsx. I have this file

```
bls_df = pd.read_excel(sys.stdin, sheet_name="MSA_dl", index_col=None)
```

But that doesn't seem to work.  Is it possible to do what I'm trying and, if so, how does one do it?

Notes:

1. The actual input file is "MSA_M2018_dl.xlsx" which is in the zip file https://www.bls.gov/oes/special.requests/oesm18ma.zip.

I download and extract the datafile like this:

```
curl -o oesm18ma.zip'https://www.bls.gov/oes/special.requests/oesm18ma.zip'
7z x oesm18ma.zip
```

2. I have solved the problem as follows, with script test01.py that reads from stdin and writes to stdout.  NOTE the use of **sys.stdin.buffer** in the read_excel() call.

   import sys
   import os
   import pandas as pd

   BLS_DF = pd.read_excel(sys.stdin.buffer, sheet_name="MSA_dl", index_col=None)

   BLS_DF.to_csv(sys.stdout, index=False)
3. I invoke this as:

   cat MSA_M2018_dl.xlsx | python3 test01.py
4. This is a small test program to illustrate the idea while removing complexity.  It's not the actual program I'm working on.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the sys.stdin is a string of the excel file you would like to read?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "string."  It is the actual contents of the excel file. Say my program above was called foo.py, then I would like to invoke something like:

cat excelfile.xlsx | python3 foo.py

Comment: string as in, the `type()` that returns string. You're going to need to provide us more background. Sample data, and more code. I don't understand when you say "it's the actual content of the excel file"

Comment: Of course. excel files are binary not text.

Comment: I can read excel from stdin using pandas, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/59468669/1782641 My problem is that pandas only seems to successfully read from stdin when using `< /path/to/file.xlsx` and not `cat /path/to/file.xlsx |`

Answer (score 1):

Basing on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20697069/6945436) answer, a possibility would be:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import io

csv = ""
for line in sys.stdin:
    csv += line

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv))
```

Comment: The source file is an xlsx, not csv.

Comment: You can't simply use cat to output an xlsx file, you either need to convert it first, for example using xlsx2csv, and then treat it like a csv or need to find a way to provide it as a stream of bytes i suppose

Comment: I think the xlsx2csv would work, though I did find a way of doing it directly as I noted in my revised question above.