# Basic python question regarding CSV fiiles

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am learning python and I have been stuck trying to figure why this script won't work.

I have a csv file with a header, and I input it into terminal as the an argument

The following script works fine, it lets me reiterate through each line of my csv file

```
import sys

input = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for line in input:
    print(line)
```

But when I try to convert my column index and headers into a dictionary

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

input = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

csvfile = pd.read_csv(input)
columnheader_dict= {csvfile.columns.get_loc(i):i for i in csvfile.columns}

for line in input:
    print(line)
```

print(line) doesnt print anything. Why won't it let me reiterate through each row in my csv file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas.read\_csv from string or package data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696479/pandas-read-csv-from-string-or-package-data)

Comment: Hi @GurkiratSingh, Thanks for the reply. I was wondering why doesn't this line work anymore  in the second script ```for line in input:
    print(line)```. I would have thought it should still work since I assigned filehandle to the variable ```input```

Comment: open() returns a generator object that is used up by pandas.

Comment: Because the reader is a iterator

Comment: Thanks Drey and @juanpa.arrivillaga for your tips! I guess more to be aware of when learning to code in python. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `open` in Python, what you're creating, the variable you've named `input` is called a *file handle*. This file object stores a cursor for where the file handler is currently pointed to in the file (this starts at 0, the beginning of the file).

When you call `for line in input.readlines()` what's actually happening in Python is that it's moving this cursor in the file forward by a line each iteration. Eventually this cursor reaches the end of the file and stays there. This is probably the same way that `pd.read_csv(input)` works, so by the time you've reached your following `for line in input.readlines()`, the cursor is already at the end of the file and there's nothing more to read.

If you wanted to modify your file so that the `for line in input.readlines()` section would work, you could tell the file object to `input.seek(0)` which moves the cursor back to the beginning of the file.

Comment: I see. Thank you for taking the time to explain this. Its been doing my head in trying to understand why nothing is printing.

Comment: @cms72 You shouldn't use `for line in input.readlines()`, that is mainly kept around for backwards compatibility. Always iterate directly over the file object `for line in input:`

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga - whats the difference of having it with or without .readlines() method? What do you mean by backwards compatibility?

Comment: @cms72 if you don't use `readlines()` then it only holds on line in memory at a time. With `readlines()` it stores the whole list in memory and then iterates over it.

Comment: I see. Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over each line, you need to use the readlines iterator

```
import sys
input = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')  # FYI, input is a python keyword, do not recommend using it
for line in input.readlines():
    print(line)
```

Comment: You can loop over `input` just fine, but it stops working when you have already looped over all the lines in the file or otherwise consumed them.

Comment: as suggested by @Max L you can set it back to the first line by doing input.seek(0)

Comment: Thanks @at14 and @tripleee for answering. I thought I could just use the same variable ```input``` since I assigned the output of pd.read_csv to a different variable ```input_csvfile```. I guess its something I have to be aware of coding in python. Thanks again!