# Extrapolate data from csv using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with few rows and columns of data. Now I intend to extrapolate or interpolate new data if the input values are not matching in the csv.

Let me describe my csv as follows.

```
type,depth,io,mux,enr
perf,1024,32,4,103.8175
perf,1024,64,4,85.643125
perf,1024,128,4,76.5559375
perf,1024,256,4,72.01246094
dense,1024,32,4,107.391875
dense,1024,64,4,88.99640625
dense,1024,128,4,79.79851563
dense,1024,256,4,75.19976563
```

If the input does not match with the depth or io value present in the csv. I would like to generate the output after extrapolation/interpolation.

For that I need to build an array from the column.

Is there anyway to store one of the columns from this csv or storing the csv as a list and from there?

I tried the following.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

this_dir, this_filename = os.path.split(__file__)
memory_file_path = os.path.join(this_dir, 'memory.csv')
memData = pd.read_csv(memory_file_path, delimiter= ',',)

class InvecasMem:
    def csvImport(self,depth,io):

        csvmem = memData.loc[(memData["type"] == "perf")
                 & (memData['depth'] == depth)
                 & (memData['io'] == io)]

        if len(csvmem) == 0:
            print("Error: Wrong configuration")
            memArr = memData.loc[(memData["type"] == "perf")]
            l = [list(row) for row in memArr.values]
            x=len(l)
        return l
```

However, I am unable to store the column into an array?

Also, is it possible to produce extrapolated values from multiple inputs as in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The desired output as in io = [32,64,128,256,32,64,128,256]
Whereas I am going to compute for depth = 512 and io = 256

Comment: Yes, it is possible to extrapolate. You can fit a regressor, using e.g. `sklearn`.

Comment: Can you post desired output?

Comment: for interpolation, ```scipy``` can do the job

Answer (score 1):

To interpolate, I'll start by loading the data

```py
import pandas
import numpy
from io import StringIO # https://stackoverflow.com/a/43312861/1164295

myfile="""type,depth,io,mux,enr
perf,1024,32,4,103.8175
perf,1024,64,4,85.643125
perf,1024,128,4,76.5559375
perf,1024,256,4,72.01246094
dense,1024,32,4,107.391875
dense,1024,64,4,88.99640625
dense,1024,128,4,79.79851563
dense,1024,256,4,75.19976563"""

df = pandas.read_csv(StringIO(myfile))
```

then insert a Nan:

```py
df.at[4,'enr'] = numpy.nan
```

Now we can use the `interpolate` method

```py
df.interpolate()
```

See the [interpolation section of the Pandas guide to missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#interpolation)

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but after interpolate I am getting the following output.

  /home/saikatchatrg/tmp/memory.csv  enr
4                               NaN  NaN

Here I do not understand how I feed the inputs which are not available in csv.

Comment: I don't have sufficient context to understand the specific problem you're seeing. Are you asking how to insert a new row? Also, the idea of interpolation relies on the adjacent values being relevant to the new (missing) entry.

Comment: The data in myfile is stored into a csv. Now my intention is to to look into this csv and get the 'enr' value for a particular combination. When not found, it will be interpolated.