# Flask pandas.read_excel not working - 'no such file or directory' - whilst pandas.read-csv works for equivalent CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, flask

The following method for uploading data to database (mongodb) works for CSV files but not for Excel files, despite using read_csv and read_excel respectively. I have also tried to fiddle with parameters for read_excel without any success.

The error I continue to receive is

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data2.xlsx'
```

The CSV and Excel file data are identical, except for the different file type.

```
@app.route('/<string:dbase>/fileupload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def file_upload(dbase):
    mydb = client[dbase]
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        file = request.form.get('fileupload')
        split = os.path.splitext(file) # split[1] becomes file extension name e.g. '.xlsx' or '.csv'
        if split[1] == '.xlsx' or split[1] == '.xls' or split[1] == '.xlsm' or split[1] == '.xlsb' or split[1] == '.ods':
            df=pd.read_excel(file)
        if split[1] == '.csv':
            df=pd.read_csv(file)
        accounts = df['Account'].tolist()
        accs_to_add=[]
        for acc in accounts:
            accs_to_add.append(acc)
        accs_to_add = list(set(accs_to_add))
        for acc in accs_to_add:
            accs_col.insert_one({'Account':acc})              
        return 'done'
    else:
        return render_template('file_upload.html', dbase=dbase)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: i think you should use `file = request.files['file']`

Comment: But it works for CSV files, so the form is working and form.request.get is working it seems.

Comment: i think that csv is already in your flask folder.

Comment: pandas needs a file like object to use read_csv / read_excel, The following solution should be a drop-in option for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696479/pandas-read-csv-from-string-or-package-data