# how would I convert CSV obtained from tab separated file into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert the output of this code into a dataframe. The code takes a tab-separated txt file from AWS S3 and turns it into a csv

```
>>> txt = s3.Bucket('compound-bioactivity-original-files').Object('helper-files/kinhub_human_kinase_list_30092021.txt').get()['Body'].read().decode('ascii')
>>>
>>> lines = txt.split('\n')
>>>
>>> for line in lines:
...     fields = line.split('\t')
...     print(fields)
...
['xName', 'Manning Name', 'HGNC Name', 'Kinase Name', 'Group', 'Family', 'SubFamily', 'UniprotID']
['ABL1', 'ABL', 'ABL1', 'Tyrosine-protein kinase ABL1', 'TK', 'Abl', '', 'P00519']
['ACK', 'ACK', 'TNK2', 'Activated CDC42 kinase 1', 'TK', 'Ack', '', 'Q07912']
['ACTR2', 'ACTR2', 'ACVR2A', 'Activin receptor type-2A', 'TKL', 'STKR', 'STKR2', 'P27037']
['ACTR2B', 'ACTR2B', 'ACVR2B', 'Activin receptor type-2B', 'TKL', 'STKR', 'STKR2', 'Q13705']
['ADCK4', 'ADCK4', 'ADCK4', 'Uncharacterized aarF domain-containing protein kinase 4', 'Atypical', 'ABC1', 'ABC1-A', 'Q96D53']
['Trb1', 'Trb1', 'TRIB1', 'Tribbles homolog 1', 'CAMK', 'Trbl', '', 'Q96RU8']
['BRSK2', 'BRSK2', 'BRSK2', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase BRSK2', 'CAMK', 'CAMKL', 'BRSK', 'Q8IWQ3']
['Wnk2', 'Wnk2', 'WNK2', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase WNK2', 'Other', 'WNK', '', 'Q9Y3S1']
['AKT1', 'AKT1', 'AKT1', 'RAC-alpha serine/threonine-protein kinase', 'AGC', 'Akt', '', 'P31749']
['AKT2', 'AKT2', 'AKT2', 'RAC-beta serine/threonine-protein kinase', 'AGC', 'Akt', '', 'P31751']
['AKT3', 'AKT3', 'AKT3', 'RAC-gamma serine/threonine-protein kinase', 'AGC', 'Akt', '', 'Q9Y243']
['CaMK1g', 'CaMK1g', 'CAMK1G', 'Calcium/calmodulin-dependent protein kinase type 1G', 'CAMK', 'CAMK1', '', 'Q96NX5']
['ALK', 'ALK', 'ALK', 'ALK tyrosine kinase receptor', 'TK', 'ALK', '', 'Q9UM73']
['ALK1', 'ALK1', 'ACVRL1', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase receptor R3', 'TKL', 'STKR', 'STKR1', 'P37023']
['ALK2', 'ALK2', 'ACVR1', 'Activin receptor type-1', 'TKL', 'STKR', 'STKR1', 'Q04771']
['BMPR1A', 'BMPR1A', 'BMPR1A', 'Bone morphogenetic protein receptor type-1A', 'TKL', 'STKR', 'STKR1', 'P36894']
['ALK4', 'ALK4', 'ACVR1B', 'Activin receptor type-1B', 'TKL', 'STKR', 'STKR1', 'P36896']
['TGFbR1', 'TGFbR1', 'TGFBR1', 'TGF-beta receptor type-1', 'TKL', 'STKR', 'STKR1', 'P36897']
['BMPR1B', 'BMPR1B', 'BMPR1B', 'Bone morphogenetic protein receptor type-1B', 'TKL', 'STKR', 'STKR1', 'O00238']
['AMPKa1', 'AMPKa1', 'PRKAA1', "5'-AMP-activated protein kinase catalytic subunit alpha-1", 'CAMK', 'CAMKL', 'AMPK', 'Q13131']
['AMPKa2', 'AMPKa2', 'PRKAA2', "5'-AMP-activated protein kinase catalytic subunit alpha-2", 'CAMK', 'CAMKL', 'AMPK', 'P54646']
['ANPa', 'ANPa', 'NPR1', 'Atrial natriuretic peptide receptor 1', 'RGC', 'RGC', '', 'P16066']
['ANPb', 'ANPb', 'NPR2', 'Atrial natriuretic peptide receptor 2', 'RGC', 'RGC', '', 'P20594']
['ARAF', 'ARAF', 'ARAF', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase A-Raf', 'TKL', 'RAF', '', 'P10398']
['ABL2', 'ARG', 'ABL2', 'Abelson tyrosine-protein kinase 2', 'TK', 'Abl', '', 'P42684']
['ATM', 'ATM', 'ATM', 'Serine-protein kinase ATM', 'Atypical', 'PIKK', 'ATM', 'Q13315']
['ATR', 'ATR', 'ATR', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase ATR', 'Atypical', 'PIKK', 'ATR', 'Q13535']
['AurC', 'AurC', 'AURKC', 'Aurora kinase C', 'Other', 'Aur', '', 'Q9UQB9']
['AXL', 'AXL', 'AXL', 'Tyrosine-protein kinase receptor UFO', 'TK', 'Axl', '', 'P30530']
['BARK1', 'BARK1', 'ADRBK1', 'Beta-adrenergic receptor kinase 1', 'AGC', 'GRK', 'BARK', 'P25098']
['BCKDK', 'BCKDK', 'BCKDK', '[3-methyl-2-oxobutanoate dehydrogenase [lipoamide]] kinase', 'Atypical', 'PDHK', '', 'O14874']
['GCK', 'GCK', 'MAP4K2', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase kinase kinase 2', 'STE', 'STE20', 'KHS', 'Q12851']
['BLK', 'BLK', 'BLK', 'Tyrosine-protein kinase Blk', 'TK', 'Src', '', 'P51451']
['BRAF', 'BRAF', 'BRAF', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase B-raf', 'TKL', 'RAF', '', 'P15056']
['BRK', 'BRK', 'PTK6', 'Protein-tyrosine kinase 6', 'TK', 'Src', '', 'Q13882']
['BTK', 'BTK', 'BTK', 'Tyrosine-protein kinase BTK', 'TK', 'Tec', '', 'Q06187']
['BUBR1', 'BUBR1', 'BUB1B', 'Mitotic checkpoint serine/threonine-protein kinase BUB1 beta', 'Other', 'BUB', '', 'O60566']
['CDK7', 'CDK7', 'CDK7', 'Cyclin-dependent kinase 7', 'CMGC', 'CDK', 'CDK7', 'P50613']
['CaMK1a', 'CaMK1a', 'CAMK1', 'Calcium/calmodulin-dependent protein kinase type 1', 'CAMK', 'CAMK1', '', 'Q14012']
['CaMK2a', 'CaMK2a', 'CAMK2A', 'Calcium/calmodulin-dependent protein kinase type II subunit alpha', 'CAMK', 'CAMK2', '', 'Q9UQM7']
['CaMK2b', 'CaMK2b', 'CAMK2B', 'Calcium/calmodulin-dependent protein kinase type II subunit beta', 'CAMK', 'CAMK2', '', 'Q13554']
['CaMK2g', 'CaMK2g', 'CAMK2G', 'Calcium/calmodulin-dependent protein kinase (CaM kinase) II gamma', 'CAMK', 'CAMK2', '', 'Q13555']
['CaMK4', 'CaMK4', 'CAMK4', 'Calcium/calmodulin-dependent protein kinase type IV', 'CAMK', 'CAMK1', '', 'Q16566']
['VACAMKL', 'VACAMKL', 'CAMKV', 'CaM kinase-like vesicle-associated protein', 'CAMK', 'CAMK-Unique', '', 'Q8NCB2']
['DCAMKL1', 'DCAMKL1', 'DCLK1', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase DCLK1', 'CAMK', 'DCAMKL', '', 'O15075']
['CASK', 'CASK', 'CASK', 'Peripheral plasma membrane protein CASK', 'CAMK', 'CASK', '', 'O14936']
['CDC2', 'CDC2', 'CDK1', 'Cyclin-dependent kinase 1', 'CMGC', 'CDK', 'CDC2', 'P06493']
['CDC7', 'CDC7', 'CDC7', 'Cell division cycle 7-related protein kinase', 'Other', 'CDC7', '', 'O00311']
['CDK2', 'CDK2', 'CDK2', 'Cyclin-dependent kinase 2', 'CMGC', 'CDK', 'CDK2', 'P24941']
['CDK3', 'CDK3', 'CDK3', 'Cyclin-dependent kinase 3', 'CMGC', 'CDK', 'CDK2', 'Q00526']
['CDK4', 'CDK4', 'CDK4', 'Cyclin-dependent kinase 4', 'CMGC', 'CDK', 'CDK4', 'P11802']
['CDK5', 'CDK5', 'CDK5', 'Cyclin-dependent kinase 5', 'CMGC', 'CDK', 'CDK5', 'Q00535']
['CDK6', 'CDK6', 'CDK6', 'Cyclin-dependent kinase 6', 'CMGC', 'CDK', 'CDK4', 'Q00534']
['CDK8', 'CDK8', 'CDK8', 'Cyclin-dependent kinase 8', 'CMGC', 'CDK', 'CDK8', 'P49336']
['PKG1', 'PKG1', 'PRKG1', 'cGMP-dependent protein kinase', 'AGC', 'PKG', '', 'Q13976']
['PKG2', 'PKG2', 'PRKG2', 'cGMP-dependent protein kinase 2', 'AGC', 'PKG', '', 'Q13237']
['CHED', 'CHED', 'CDK13', 'Cyclin-dependent kinase 13', 'CMGC', 'CDK', 'CRK7', 'Q14004']
['CHK1', 'CHK1', 'CHEK1', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase Chk1', 'CAMK', 'CAMKL', 'CHK1', 'O14757']
['CHK2', 'CHK2', 'CHEK2', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase Chk2', 'CAMK', 'RAD53', '', 'O96017']
['CK1a', 'CK1a', 'CSNK1A1', 'Casein kinase I isoform alpha', 'CK1', 'CK1', '', 'P48729']
['CK1d', 'CK1d', 'CSNK1D', 'Casein kinase I isoform delta', 'CK1', 'CK1', '', 'P48730']
['CK1e', 'CK1e', 'CSNK1E', 'Casein kinase I isoform epsilon', 'CK1', 'CK1', '', 'P49674']
['CK1g2', 'CK1g2', 'CSNK1G2', 'Casein kinase I isoform gamma-2', 'CK1', 'CK1', '', 'P78368']
['CK1g3', 'CK1g3', 'CSNK1G3', 'Casein kinase I isoform gamma-3', 'CK1', 'CK1', '', 'Q9Y6M4']
['CK2a1', 'CK2a1', 'CSNK2A1', 'Casein kinase II subunit alpha', 'CMGC', 'CK2', '', 'P68400']
['CK2a2', 'CK2a2', 'CSNK2A2', "Casein kinase II subunit alpha'", 'CMGC', 'CK2', '', 'P19784']
['CLK1', 'CLK1', 'CLK1', 'Dual specificity protein kinase CLK1', 'CMGC', 'CLK', '', 'P49759']
['CLK2', 'CLK2', 'CLK2', 'Dual specificity protein kinase CLK2', 'CMGC', 'CLK', '', 'P49760']
['CLK3', 'CLK3', 'CLK3', 'Dual specificity protein kinase CLK3', 'CMGC', 'CLK', '', 'P49761']
['COT', 'COT', 'MAP3K8', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase kinase 8', 'STE', 'STE-Unique', '', 'P41279']
['FMS', 'FMS', 'CSF1R', 'Macrophage colony-stimulating factor 1 receptor', 'TK', 'PDGFR', '', 'P07333']
['CSK', 'CSK', 'CSK', 'Tyrosine-protein kinase CSK', 'TK', 'Csk', '', 'P41240']
['MARK3', 'MARK3', 'MARK3', 'MAP/microtubule affinity-regulating kinase 3', 'CAMK', 'CAMKL', 'MARK', 'P27448']
['CYGD', 'CYGD', 'GUCY2D', 'Retinal guanylyl cyclase 1', 'RGC', 'RGC', '', 'Q02846']
['CYGF', 'CYGF', 'GUCY2F', 'Retinal guanylyl cyclase 2', 'RGC', 'RGC', '', 'P51841']
['DAPK1', 'DAPK1', 'DAPK1', 'Death-associated protein kinase 1', 'CAMK', 'DAPK', '', 'P53355']
['DAPK2', 'DAPK2', 'DAPK2', 'Death-associated protein kinase 2', 'CAMK', 'DAPK', '', 'Q9UIK4']
['DLK', 'DLK', 'MAP3K12', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase kinase 12', 'TKL', 'MLK', 'LZK', 'Q12852']
['DMPK1', 'DMPK1', 'DMPK', 'Myotonin-protein kinase', 'AGC', 'DMPK', 'GEK', 'Q09013']
['DMPK2', 'DMPK2', 'CDC42BPG', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase MRCK gamma', 'AGC', 'DMPK', 'GEK', 'Q6DT37']
['DNAPK', 'DNAPK', 'PRKDC', 'DNA-dependent protein kinase catalytic subunit', 'Atypical', 'PIKK', 'DNAPK', 'P78527']
['DYRK1B', 'DYRK1B', 'DYRK1B', 'Dual specificity tyrosine-phosphorylation-regulated kinase 1B', 'CMGC', 'DYRK', 'DYRK1', 'Q9Y463']
['DYRK2', 'DYRK2', 'DYRK2', 'Dual specificity tyrosine-phosphorylation-regulated kinase 2', 'CMGC', 'DYRK', 'DYRK2', 'Q92630']
['DYRK4', 'DYRK4', 'DYRK4', 'Dual specificity tyrosine-phosphorylation-regulated kinase 4', 'CMGC', 'DYRK', 'DYRK2', 'Q9NR20']
['eEF2K', 'eEF2K', 'EEF2K', 'Eukaryotic elongation factor 2 kinase', 'Atypical', 'Alpha', 'eEF2K', 'O00418']
['EGFR', 'EGFR', 'EGFR', 'Epidermal growth factor receptor', 'TK', 'EGFR', '', 'P00533']
['PKR', 'PKR', 'EIF2AK2', 'Interferon-induced', 'Other', 'PEK', '', 'P19525']
['MARK2', 'MARK2', 'MARK2', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase MARK2', 'CAMK', 'CAMKL', 'MARK', 'Q7KZI7']
['EphA1', 'EphA1', 'EPHA1', 'Ephrin type-A receptor 1', 'TK', 'Eph', '', 'P21709']
['EphA2', 'EphA2', 'EPHA2', 'Ephrin type-A receptor 2', 'TK', 'Eph', '', 'P29317']
['EphA3', 'EphA3', 'EPHA3', 'Ephrin type-A receptor 3', 'TK', 'Eph', '', 'P29320']
['EphA4', 'EphA4', 'EPHA4', 'Ephrin type-A receptor 4', 'TK', 'Eph', '', 'P54764']
['EphA5', 'EphA5', 'EPHA5', 'Ephrin type-A receptor 5', 'TK', 'Eph', '', 'P54756']
['EphA8', 'EphA8', 'EPHA8', 'Ephrin type-A receptor 8', 'TK', 'Eph', '', 'P29322']
['EphB1', 'EphB1', 'EPHB1', 'Ephrin type-B receptor 1', 'TK', 'Eph', '', 'P54762']
['EphB2', 'EphB2', 'EPHB2', 'Ephrin type-B receptor 2', 'TK', 'Eph', '', 'P29323']
['EphB3', 'EphB3', 'EPHB3', 'Ephrin type-B receptor 3', 'TK', 'Eph', '', 'P54753']
['EphB4', 'EphB4', 'EPHB4', 'Ephrin type-B receptor 4', 'TK', 'Eph', '', 'P54760']
['EphB6', 'EphB6', 'EPHB6', 'Ephrin type-B receptor 6', 'TK', 'Eph', '', 'O15197']
['Erk1', 'Erk1', 'MAPK3', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase 3', 'CMGC', 'MAPK', 'ERK1', 'P27361']
['Erk2', 'Erk2', 'MAPK1', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase 1', 'CMGC', 'MAPK', 'ERK1', 'P28482']
['Erk3', 'Erk3', 'MAPK6', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase 6', 'CMGC', 'MAPK', 'ERK3', 'Q16659']
['Erk4', 'Erk4', 'MAPK4', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase 4', 'CMGC', 'MAPK', 'ERK3', 'P31152']
['FAK', 'FAK', 'PTK2', 'Focal adhesion kinase 1', 'TK', 'FAK', '', 'Q05397']
['FER', 'FER', 'FER', 'Tyrosine-protein kinase Fer', 'TK', 'Fer', '', 'P16591']
['FES', 'FES', 'FES', 'Tyrosine-protein kinase Fes/Fps', 'TK', 'Fer', '', 'P07332']
['FGFR1', 'FGFR1', 'FGFR1', 'Fibroblast growth factor receptor 1', 'TK', 'FGFR', '', 'P11362']
['FGFR2', 'FGFR2', 'FGFR2', 'Fibroblast growth factor receptor 2', 'TK', 'FGFR', '', 'P21802']
['FGFR3', 'FGFR3', 'FGFR3', 'Fibroblast growth factor receptor 3', 'TK', 'FGFR', '', 'P22607']
['FGFR4', 'FGFR4', 'FGFR4', 'Fibroblast growth factor receptor 4', 'TK', 'FGFR', '', 'P22455']
['FGR', 'FGR', 'FGR', 'Tyrosine-protein kinase Fgr', 'TK', 'Src', '', 'P09769']
['FLT3', 'FLT3', 'FLT3', 'Receptor-type tyrosine-protein kinase FLT3', 'TK', 'PDGFR', '', 'P36888']
['FLT1', 'FLT1', 'FLT1', 'Vascular endothelial growth factor receptor 1', 'TK', 'VEGFR', '', 'P17948']
['FLT4', 'FLT4', 'FLT4', 'Vascular endothelial growth factor receptor 3', 'TK', 'VEGFR', '', 'P35916']
['FRAP', 'FRAP', 'MTOR', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase mTOR', 'Atypical', 'PIKK', 'FRAP', 'P42345']
['FYN', 'FYN', 'FYN', 'Tyrosine-protein kinase Fyn', 'TK', 'Src', '', 'P06241']
['GAK', 'GAK', 'GAK', 'Cyclin-G-associated kinase', 'Other', 'NAK', '', 'O14976']
['GPRK4', 'GPRK4', 'GRK4', 'G protein-coupled receptor kinase 4', 'AGC', 'GRK', 'GRK', 'P32298']
['GPRK5', 'GPRK5', 'GRK5', 'G protein-coupled receptor kinase 5', 'AGC', 'GRK', 'GRK', 'P34947']
['GPRK6', 'GPRK6', 'GRK6', 'G protein-coupled receptor kinase 6', 'AGC', 'GRK', 'GRK', 'P43250']
['Trb2', 'Trb2', 'TRIB2', 'Tribbles homolog 2', 'CAMK', 'Trbl', '', 'Q92519']
['GSK3A', 'GSK3A', 'GSK3A', 'Glycogen synthase kinase-3 alpha', 'CMGC', 'GSK', '', 'P49840']
['GSK3B', 'GSK3B', 'GSK3B', 'Glycogen synthase kinase-3 beta', 'CMGC', 'GSK', '', 'P49841']
['HCK', 'HCK', 'HCK', 'Tyrosine-protein kinase HCK', 'TK', 'Src', '', 'P08631']
['ErbB2', 'HER2/ErbB2', 'ERBB2', 'Receptor tyrosine-protein kinase erbB-2', 'TK', 'EGFR', '', 'P04626']
['ErbB3', 'HER3/ErbB3', 'ERBB3', 'Receptor tyrosine-protein kinase erbB-3', 'TK', 'EGFR', '', 'P21860']
['ErbB4', 'HER4/ErbB4', 'ERBB4', 'Receptor tyrosine-protein kinase erbB-4', 'TK', 'EGFR', '', 'Q15303']
['HIPK1', 'HIPK1', 'HIPK1', 'Homeodomain-interacting protein kinase 1', 'CMGC', 'DYRK', 'HIPK', 'Q86Z02']
['HPK1', 'HPK1', 'MAP4K1', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase kinase kinase 1', 'STE', 'STE20', 'KHS', 'Q92918']
['HSER', 'HSER', 'GUCY2C', 'Heat-stable enterotoxin receptor', 'RGC', 'RGC', '', 'P25092']
['IGF1R', 'IGF1R', 'IGF1R', 'Insulin-like growth factor 1 receptor', 'TK', 'InsR', '', 'P08069']
['IKKa', 'IKKa', 'CHUK', 'Inhibitor of nuclear factor kappa-B kinase subunit alpha', 'Other', 'IKK', '', 'O15111']
['IKKb', 'IKKb', 'IKBKB', 'Inhibitor of nuclear factor kappa-B kinase subunit beta', 'Other', 'IKK', '', 'O14920']
['ILK', 'ILK', 'ILK', 'Integrin-linked protein kinase', 'TKL', 'MLK', 'ILK', 'Q13418']
['INSR', 'INSR', 'INSR', 'Insulin receptor', 'TK', 'InsR', '', 'P06213']
['IRAK1', 'IRAK1', 'IRAK1', 'Interleukin-1 receptor-associated kinase 1', 'TKL', 'IRAK', '', 'P51617']
['IRAK2', 'IRAK2', 'IRAK2', 'Interleukin-1 receptor-associated kinase-like 2', 'TKL', 'IRAK', '', 'O43187']
['IRAK3', 'IRAK3', 'IRAK3', 'Interleukin-1 receptor-associated kinase 3', 'TKL', 'IRAK', '', 'Q9Y616']
['IRE1', 'IRE1', 'ERN1', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase/endoribonuclease IRE1', 'Other', 'IRE', '', 'O75460']
['IRR', 'IRR', 'INSRR', 'Insulin receptor-related protein', 'TK', 'InsR', '', 'P14616']
['ITK', 'ITK', 'ITK', 'Tyrosine-protein kinase ITK/TSK', 'TK', 'Tec', '', 'Q08881']
['JAK1', 'JAK1', 'JAK1', 'Tyrosine-protein kinase JAK1', 'TK', 'Jak', '', 'P23458']
['JAK2', 'JAK2', 'JAK2', 'Tyrosine-protein kinase JAK2', 'TK', 'Jak', '', 'O60674']
['JAK3', 'JAK3', 'JAK3', 'Tyrosine-protein kinase JAK3', 'TK', 'Jak', '', 'P52333']
['JNK1', 'JNK1', 'MAPK8', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase 8', 'CMGC', 'MAPK', 'JNK', 'P45983']
['JNK2', 'JNK2', 'MAPK9', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase 9', 'CMGC', 'MAPK', 'JNK', 'P45984']
['JNK3', 'JNK3', 'MAPK10', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase 10', 'CMGC', 'MAPK', 'JNK', 'P53779']
['KHS1', 'KHS1', 'MAP4K5', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase kinase kinase 5', 'STE', 'STE20', 'KHS', 'Q9Y4K4']
['IKKe', 'IKKe', 'IKBKE', 'Inhibitor of nuclear factor kappa-B kinase subunit epsilon', 'Other', 'IKK', '', 'Q14164']
['NuaK1', 'NuaK1', 'NUAK1', 'NUAK family SNF1-like kinase 1', 'CAMK', 'CAMKL', 'NuaK', 'O60285']
['MAST3', 'MAST3', 'MAST3', 'Microtubule-associated serine/threonine-protein kinase 3', 'AGC', 'MAST', '', 'O60307']
['Fused', 'Fused', 'STK36', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase 36', 'Other', 'ULK', '', 'Q9NRP7']
['PIM3', 'PIM3', 'PIM3', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase pim-3', 'CAMK', 'PIM', '', 'Q86V86']
['KIT', 'KIT', 'KIT', 'Mast/stem cell growth factor receptor Kit', 'TK', 'PDGFR', '', 'P10721']
['CDKL2', 'CDKL2', 'CDKL2', 'Cyclin-dependent kinase-like 2', 'CMGC', 'CDKL', '', 'Q92772']
['CDKL1', 'CDKL1', 'CDKL1', 'Cyclin-dependent kinase-like 1', 'CMGC', 'CDKL', '', 'Q00532']
['KSR1', 'KSR1', 'KSR1', 'Kinase suppressor of Ras 1', 'TKL', 'RAF', 'KSR', 'Q8IVT5']
['LCK', 'LCK', 'LCK', 'Tyrosine-protein kinase Lck', 'TK', 'Src', '', 'P06239']
['LIMK2', 'LIMK2', 'LIMK2', 'LIM domain kinase 2', 'TKL', 'LISK', 'LIMK', 'P53671']
['LKB1', 'LKB1', 'STK11', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase STK11', 'CAMK', 'CAMKL', 'LKB', 'Q15831']
['LTK', 'LTK', 'LTK', 'Leukocyte tyrosine kinase receptor', 'TK', 'ALK', '', 'P29376']
['LYN', 'LYN', 'LYN', 'Tyrosine-protein kinase Lyn', 'TK', 'Src', '', 'P07948']
['MAK', 'MAK', 'MAK', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase MAK', 'CMGC', 'RCK', '', 'P20794']
['MAPKAPK2', 'MAPKAPK2', 'MAPKAPK2', 'MAP kinase-activated protein kinase 2', 'CAMK', 'MAPKAPK', 'MK2', 'P49137']
['MAPKAPK3', 'MAPKAPK3', 'MAPKAPK3', 'MAP kinase-activated protein kinase 3', 'CAMK', 'MAPKAPK', 'MK2', 'Q16644']
['MAPKAPK5', 'MAPKAPK5', 'MAPKAPK5', 'MAP kinase-activated protein kinase 5', 'CAMK', 'MAPKAPK', 'MK5', 'Q8IW41']
['MARK1', 'MARK1', 'MARK1', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase MARK1', 'CAMK', 'CAMKL', 'MARK', 'Q9P0L2']
['MAST2', 'MAST2', 'MAST2', 'Microtubule-associated serine/threonine-protein kinase 2', 'AGC', 'MAST', '', 'Q6P0Q8']
['MAP2K1', 'MAP2K1', 'MAP2K1', 'Dual specificity mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase 1', 'STE', 'STE7', '', 'Q02750']
['MAP2K2', 'MAP2K2', 'MAP2K2', 'Dual specificity mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase 2', 'STE', 'STE7', '', 'P36507']
['MAP2K5', 'MAP2K5', 'MAP2K5', 'Dual specificity mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase 5', 'STE', 'STE7', '', 'Q13163']
['MAP2K6', 'MAP2K6', 'MAP2K6', 'Dual specificity mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase 6', 'STE', 'STE7', '', 'P52564']
['MAP3K1', 'MAP3K1', 'MAP3K1', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase kinase 1', 'STE', 'STE11', '', 'Q13233']
['MAP3K2', 'MAP3K2', 'MAP3K2', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase kinase 2', 'STE', 'STE11', '', 'Q9Y2U5']
['MAP3K3', 'MAP3K3', 'MAP3K3', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase kinase 3', 'STE', 'STE11', '', 'Q99759']
['MAP3K4', 'MAP3K4', 'MAP3K4', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase kinase 4', 'STE', 'STE11', '', 'Q9Y6R4']
['MAP3K5', 'MAP3K5', 'MAP3K5', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase kinase 5', 'STE', 'STE11', '', 'Q99683']
['MER', 'MER', 'MERTK', 'Tyrosine-protein kinase Mer', 'TK', 'Axl', '', 'Q12866']
['MET', 'MET', 'MET', 'Hepatocyte growth factor receptor', 'TK', 'Met', '', 'P08581']
['MISR2', 'MISR2', 'AMHR2', 'Anti-Muellerian hormone type-2 receptor', 'TKL', 'STKR', 'STKR2', 'Q16671']
['MAP2K7', 'MAP2K7', 'MAP2K7', 'Dual specificity mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase 7', 'STE', 'STE7', '', 'O14733']
['smMLCK', 'smMLCK', 'MYLK', 'Myosin light chain kinase', 'CAMK', 'MLCK', '', 'Q15746']
['MLK1', 'MLK1', 'MAP3K9', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase kinase 9', 'TKL', 'MLK', 'MLK', 'P80192']
['MLK2', 'MLK2', 'MAP3K10', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase kinase 10', 'TKL', 'MLK', 'MLK', 'Q02779']
['DYRK1A', 'DYRK1A', 'DYRK1A', 'Dual specificity tyrosine-phosphorylation-regulated kinase 1A', 'CMGC', 'DYRK', 'DYRK1', 'Q13627']
['MNK1', 'MNK1', 'MKNK1', 'MAP kinase-interacting serine/threonine-protein kinase 1', 'CAMK', 'MAPKAPK', 'MNK', 'Q9BUB5']
['MNK2', 'MNK2', 'MKNK2', 'MAP kinase-interacting serine/threonine-protein kinase 2', 'CAMK', 'MAPKAPK', 'MNK', 'Q9HBH9']
['MOS', 'MOS', 'MOS', 'Proto-oncogene serine/threonine-protein kinase mos', 'Other', 'MOS', '', 'P00540']
['MAP2K3', 'MAP2K3', 'MAP2K3', 'Dual specificity mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase 3', 'STE', 'STE7', '', 'P46734']
['MAP2K4', 'MAP2K4', 'MAP2K4', 'Dual specificity mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase 4', 'STE', 'STE7', '', 'P45985']
['MRCKb', 'MRCKb', 'CDC42BPB', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase MRCK beta', 'AGC', 'DMPK', 'GEK', 'Q9Y5S2']
['MSK1', 'MSK1', 'RPS6KA5', 'Ribosomal protein S6 kinase alpha-5', 'AGC', 'RSK', 'MSK', 'O75582']
['MSK2', 'MSK2', 'RPS6KA4', 'Ribosomal protein S6 kinase alpha-4', 'AGC', 'RSK', 'MSK', 'O75676']
['MST1', 'MST1', 'STK4', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase 4', 'STE', 'STE20', 'MST', 'Q13043']
['MST2', 'MST2', 'STK3', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase 3', 'STE', 'STE20', 'MST', 'Q13188']
['MST3', 'MST3', 'STK24', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase 24', 'STE', 'STE20', 'YSK', 'Q9Y6E0']
['MUSK', 'MUSK', 'MUSK', 'Muscle', 'TK', 'Musk', '', 'O15146']
['MYT1', 'MYT1', 'PKMYT1', 'Membrane-associated tyrosine- and threonine-specific cdc2-inhibitory kinase', 'Other', 'WEE', '', 'Q99640']
['NDR1', 'NDR1', 'STK38', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase 38', 'AGC', 'NDR', '', 'Q15208']
['NEK1', 'NEK1', 'NEK1', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase Nek1', 'Other', 'NEK', '', 'Q96PY6']
['NEK2', 'NEK2', 'NEK2', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase Nek2', 'Other', 'NEK', '', 'P51955']
['NEK3', 'NEK3', 'NEK3', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase Nek3', 'Other', 'NEK', '', 'P51956']
['NIK', 'NIK', 'MAP3K14', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase kinase 14', 'STE', 'STE-Unique', '', 'Q99558']
['NLK', 'NLK', 'NLK', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase NLK', 'CMGC', 'MAPK', 'nmo', 'Q9UBE8']
['NEK4', 'NEK4', 'NEK4', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase Nek4', 'Other', 'NEK', '', 'P51957']
['IRAK4', 'IRAK4', 'IRAK4', 'Interleukin-1 receptor-associated kinase 4', 'TKL', 'IRAK', '', 'Q9NWZ3']
['PIK3R4', 'PIK3R4', 'PIK3R4', 'Phosphoinositide 3-kinase regulatory subunit 4', 'Other', 'VPS15', '', 'Q99570']
['ROCK2', 'ROCK2', 'ROCK2', 'Rho-associated protein kinase 2', 'AGC', 'DMPK', 'ROCK', 'O75116']
['p38a', 'p38a', 'MAPK14', 'Mitogen-activated protein kinase 14', 'CMGC', 'MAPK', 'p38', 'Q16539']
['p70S6K', 'p70S6K', 'RPS6KB1', 'Ribosomal protein S6 kinase beta-1', 'AGC', 'RSK', 'RSKp70', 'P23443']
['p70S6Kb', 'p70S6Kb', 'RPS6KB2', 'Ribosomal protein S6 kinase beta-2', 'AGC', 'RSK', 'RSKp70', 'Q9UBS0']
['PAK1', 'PAK1', 'PAK1', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase PAK 1', 'STE', 'STE20', 'PAKA', 'Q13153']
['PAK2', 'PAK2', 'PAK2', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase PAK 2', 'STE', 'STE20', 'PAKA', 'Q13177']
['PAK3', 'PAK3', 'PAK3', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase PAK 3', 'STE', 'STE20', 'PAKA', 'O75914']
['PKCh', 'PKCh', 'PRKCH', 'Protein kinase C eta type', 'AGC', 'PKC', 'PKCh', 'P24723']
['PCTAIRE1', 'PCTAIRE1', 'CDK16', 'Cyclin-dependent kinase 16', 'CMGC', 'CDK', 'PCTAIRE', 'Q00536']
['PCTAIRE2', 'PCTAIRE2', 'CDK17', 'Cyclin-dependent kinase 17', 'CMGC', 'CDK', 'PCTAIRE', 'Q00537']
['PCTAIRE3', 'PCTAIRE3', 'CDK18', 'Cyclin-dependent kinase 18', 'CMGC', 'CDK', 'PCTAIRE', 'Q07002']
['PDGFRa', 'PDGFRa', 'PDGFRA', 'Platelet-derived growth factor receptor alpha', 'TK', 'PDGFR', '', 'P16234']
['PDGFRb', 'PDGFRb', 'PDGFRB', 'Platelet-derived growth factor receptor beta', 'TK', 'PDGFR', '', 'P09619']
['PDK1', 'PDK1', 'PDPK1', '3-phosphoinositide-dependent protein kinase 1', 'AGC', 'PDK1', '', 'O15530']
['PDHK1', 'PDHK1', 'PDK1', '[Pyruvate dehydrogenase [lipoamide]] kinase isozyme 1', 'Atypical', 'PDHK', '', 'Q15118']
['PDHK2', 'PDHK2', 'PDK2', '[Pyruvate dehydrogenase [lipoamide]] kinase isozyme 2', 'Atypical', 'PDHK', '', 'Q15119']
['PDHK3', 'PDHK3', 'PDK3', '[Pyruvate dehydrogenase [lipoamide]] kinase isozyme 3', 'Atypical', 'PDHK', '', 'Q15120']
['PDHK4', 'PDHK4', 'PDK4', '[Pyruvate dehydrogenase [lipoamide]] kinase isozyme 4', 'Atypical', 'PDHK', '', 'Q16654']
['PEK', 'PEK', 'EIF2AK3', 'Eukaryotic translation initiation factor 2-alpha kinase 3', 'Other', 'PEK', 'PEK', 'Q9NZJ5']
['PFTAIRE1', 'PFTAIRE1', 'CDK14', 'Cyclin-dependent kinase 14', 'CMGC', 'CDK', 'PFTAIRE', 'O94921']
['PHKg1', 'PHKg1', 'PHKG1', 'Phosphorylase b kinase gamma catalytic chain', 'CAMK', 'PHK', '', 'Q16816']
['PHKg2', 'PHKg2', 'PHKG2', 'Phosphorylase b kinase gamma catalytic chain', 'CAMK', 'PHK', '', 'P15735']
['PIM1', 'PIM1', 'PIM1', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase pim-1', 'CAMK', 'PIM', '', 'P11309']
['PIM2', 'PIM2', 'PIM2', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase pim-2', 'CAMK', 'PIM', '', 'Q9P1W9']
['CDK10', 'CDK10', 'CDK10', 'Cyclin-dependent kinase 10', 'CMGC', 'CDK', 'CDK10', 'Q15131']
['CDK9', 'CDK9', 'CDK9', 'Cyclin-dependent kinase 9', 'CMGC', 'CDK', 'CDK9', 'P50750']
['PITSLRE', 'PITSLRE', 'CDK11B', 'Cyclin-dependent kinase 11B', 'CMGC', 'CDK', 'CDK11', 'P21127']
['MELK', 'MELK', 'MELK', 'Maternal embryonic leucine zipper kinase', 'CAMK', 'CAMKL', 'MELK', 'Q14680']
['MRCKa', 'MRCKa', 'CDC42BPA', 'Serine/threonine-protein kinase MRCK alpha', 'AGC', 'DMPK', 'GEK', 'Q5VT25']
['PKACa', 'PKACa', 'PRKACA', 'cAMP-dependent protein kinase catalytic subunit alpha', 'AGC', 'PKA', '', 'P17612']
['PKACb', 'PKACb', 'PRKACB', 'cAMP-dependent protein kinase catalytic subunit beta', 'AGC', 'PKA', '', 'P22694']
['PKACg', 'PKACg', 'PRKACG', 'cAMP-dependent protein kinase catalytic subunit gamma', 'AGC', 'PKA', '', 'P22612']
['']
```

My only explanation for why pd.read_csv doesn't work is that my output isn't truly a CSV, it does say that it is classified as a list

```
>>> df_new = pd.read_csv(fields)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\intek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\intek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 586, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\intek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 482, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\intek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 811, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\intek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1040, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "C:\Users\intek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 51, in __init__
    self._open_handles(src, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\intek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\base_parser.py", line 222, in _open_handles
    self.handles = get_handle(
  File "C:\Users\intek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 609, in get_handle
    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
  File "C:\Users\intek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 396, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>
```

The main reason I want to do this is because I need this data to be in a dataframe because I am trying to merge the `Group`,`Family` and `Subfamily` columns to an already existing dataframe based on the `UniprotID` column that they both share using a merge function. I figured this would be the best method to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas.read\_csv from string or package data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696479/pandas-read-csv-from-string-or-package-data)

Comment: I don't think so because I did try StringIO before and I just got the error "TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not list"

Comment: Yes, you have to provide the full string (`txt`) to it, instead of the split up version

Comment: ok! thank you so much, ill try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After set "txt" variable with s3 bucket contents, do this to load to dataframe:

```
data = [x.split('\t') for x in txt.split('\n')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
```